# How to add current date in category description in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, categories

I write text for each category in description box and I need to dynamically display date in this text without editing it every month. Is there some plugin or if you could help with some code.

*Example:*

Articles for **April 2015**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by the use of shortcodes, **you would need to write your own** as there are none but it looks some like this;

```
> description: Lorem impusm asd [custom_date] another time...
```

The `[custom_date]` is a custom shortcode (you will write) in Wordpress. This is generated at run time. You add your shortcuts code in the `functions.php` file. Look at the API for writing the shortcodes.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Template of [custom_date] shortcode in `function.php`

```
// [custom_date date="15/03/2015"]
function custom_date_func($atts) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'date' => '01/01/1900' //default value for `date` attr.
    ), $atts );

    // You can do some calculation date variable.

    return "date = {$a['date']}"; //this will return: 15/03/05
}
add_shortcode('custom_date', 'custom_date_func');
```

---

Preview of code in action

[image: Preview of code working]

Comment: @walterdesign, It works I have tested it. http://imgur.com/8z5wyQ3, Are you sure your doing everything as follows? Also your theme may not be processing short codes. Check the API.

Comment: now it works! I didn't enabled shorcodes in my theme. Now it's ok. It displays only date = 01/01/1900, but I need to display current month and a year dynamicly. Could you help me with that as well?